# Return Blank from Python flask API

Tags: python, api, flask

I have an API that must return just blank and status as 200 OK in case there is no data available

I have tried following things and facing these error

```
if df.empty:
   return '' , 200
```

This returns "" in the browser

```
if df.empty:
   return json.loads('{}'), 200
```

This return {} in the browser

Send status as 204 (NO CONTENT) makes the previous content to be as it is on the browser

How can i return complete blank with status as 200?

Comment: You should simply ```return (' ', 200)```, it will give empty response with status code 200.

Comment: Your first example just returns an empty string for me in the browser, which is exactly what you want I guess.

Comment: @SyedSaadAhmed by `return (' ', 200)`, it returns " " in the browser, i have to return blank response.

Comment: @Joost Returning Empty String in the browsers display "", the browser must refresh and show complete blank screen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found solution after thoroughly exploring Flask documents

```
from flask import Response
.....
if df.empty:
   return Response(status = 200)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first example shows in my console, as others have mention in comments:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Dec/2018 18:46:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

You can also see status of a document in a `Network` tab in Developers console.

I didn't see `204 - NO CONTENT` until I explicitly defined it:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '', 204
```

Your second example didn't work for me and gave me an error:

> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

EDIT:

This is source of a page in opera (and chrome also).

[image: Page source]

And this is code for your second example, that I get an error from.

```
from flask import Flask, json

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return json.loads('{}'), 200
```

Comment: The issue I am facing returning Blank to the browser, sending empty string display "" in the browser.
For my second example it worked correctly without any error for me, can you please share me your code snippet.

Comment: I don't want to add a blank screen as an example, but I literally get nothing. Only white screen, both in opera and in chrome. And if I check source code, it contains nothing. Check edit for this.

Comment: for the second example its
`import json`
`return json.loads('{}')`

Comment: By send 204 as response code browser doesn't refresh 
if the dataframe is null only then blank screen must be returned.